# PyGtk CellRendererCombo using Pixbuf

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, canonical-quickly

I would like to display a ComboBox in my TreeView that contains some Icons. So I created a ListStore to hold the data.

```
    # Initialize a list store for the combobox.
    priorityModel = Gtk.ListStore(GObject.TYPE_INT, GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf)
    priorityModel.append([0, self.loadPixbuf('./data/media/flag_blue.png')])
    priorityModel.append([1, self.loadPixbuf('./data/media/flag_green.png')])
    priorityModel.append([2, self.loadPixbuf('./data/media/flag_yellow.png')])
    priorityModel.append([3, self.loadPixbuf('./data/media/flag_red.png')])
```

Then I created the Gtk.CellRendererCombo object and assigned the above Gtk.ListStore as model.

```
    # Setup the priority cell renderer, ...
    self.priorityRenderer = Gtk.CellRendererCombo()
    self.priorityRenderer.set_property( 'editable', True )
    self.priorityRenderer.set_property("model", priorityModel)
    self.priorityRenderer.connect("edited", self.on_priority_changed, self.listStore, 3)
```

Finally I created a new Gtk.TreeViewColumn and assigned the CellRenderer and added it to the TreeView.

```
    # ... setup the priority column ...
    self.colPriority = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Priority", self.priorityRenderer, text=3 )

    # ... and add it to the treeview.
    self.append_column( self.colPriority )
```

All nice but how could I display the Pixbuf icon instead of the integer and how do I initialize the ComboBox using the integer? And, second question, is it possible to show only the icon when the combobox is not active and show the icon and some text when the value is changed (ComboBox active)?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf` to display the icon. See for example the excellent [Python 3 Gtk+ Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cellrenderers.html#cellrendererpixbuf).

Answering your second question: Yes. Just connect to the `"changed"` signal of the `Gtk.CellRendererCombo` and add/remove the cell renderer dynamically.